# gmail import gmail content to myapplications using javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script

i need help in gmail  get content.

i created myapps

```
       Client ID: XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com   
       Email address:   
       765792474035@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      Client secret:    
      k2f2j0fFEdAt_EDTE0ATeQ3x
      Redirect URIs:    http://localhost/
      JavaScript origins:   http://localhost/
```

my javascript function

```
          $('.invitecontact-gmail').click(function(){

          https: accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=htttp://ww.google.com/m8/feeds/redirect_uri=redirect_uri=http:///&response_type=token&client_id=XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com;

});
```

this link dipaly error: invalid_request
redirect_uri:

how to open google apps in localhost
 i tried my apps redirect_url put in localhost.
same error was comming

naybody plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

By comparing your URL with an example from [Google Developers - Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication), a handful of syntax errors and typos are evident. Since the error message you've received complains about the redirect uri, you should start by getting that right.

> https: accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
>   scope=**htttp**://**ww**.google.com/m8/feeds/**redirect_uri=redirect_uri=`http:///`**& 
>   response_type=token&
>   client_id=XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com;

The following would be syntactically correct (whitespace added for readability):

```
https: accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&                << Check this URL
  redirect_uri=<SOME-VALID_URI>&                        << Placeholder
  response_type=token&
  client_id=XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com;
```

You will need to determine what a valid URI is for your application, and replace the placeholder. For example, `redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback`.